# Can't drag files from Dolphin to Chrome

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde, dolphin

Up until a couple of weeks ago, when I would try to drag and drop files from Dolphin (the default File Manager in Kubuntu) to Chrome (e.g., to add to an email or upload a video to youtube), there were no problems.  The file would upload just fine.  However, as of a couple of weeks ago, I can't get files to upload any more when I drag and drop them from Dolphin to Chrome.

I'm being very specific in the programs mentioned, because I've tried this with a variety of other programs and it works fine.  I can drag from Thunar to Chrome.  And I can drag from Dolphin to Firefox.  But, for some reason, I can't drag from Dolphin to Chrome to upload files any more.

I tried a number of fixes.

1. I disabled all my extensions in Chrome.  Didn't work.
2. I installed the beta version of Chrome.  Didn't work.
3. I did a complete removal of Chrome and a reinstall.  Didn't work.
4. I installed Chromium instead of Chrome.  Didn't work.

Anyone have any thoughts as to why Dolphin and Chrome are no longer playing nice together when it comes to dragging and dropping files to upload them in Chrome?

System information: Running Kubuntu 15.10. Dolphin is version 15.08.2.  Chrome is stable branch 47.0.2526.106-1.

Comment: I use the KDE spin of fedora and have installed `nautilus` instead (the default GNOME file explorer). Seems to work fine for drag/drop.

Comment: This bug seems to be related to Dolphin specifically. Try to report it in the official Dolphin support forum. I am having exactly the same problem as you and sadly I couldn't find any solution or hack to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved!

Simply update your system to the latest version and it should work well for you. I had this problem before and after the latest update, it got fixed automatically.

To be more precise, you need to have the following:

**- Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.63 (64-bit)

- Dolphin 15.12.3**

At the time of writing this answer, the above two were the latest versions.