# How to copy file contents from mirage

Tags: image-viewers

I'm using the KDE spin of Fedora and [dolphin won't drag/drop to chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718161/cant-drag-files-from-dolphin-to-chrome). I really want this for getting images to google docs/imgur. I also need a proper image browser (the open-file dialogue doesn't cut it). So I use `mirage`, but its <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copies the file's path rather than the image data. How can I get the image data to chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Still using `mirage`, [this script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/266761/54030) to copy a file's contents and a custom action (`Edit -> Custom Action`) does the job.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
command -v xclip >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "Need command xclip. Aborting." >&2; exit 1; }
[[ -f "$1" ]] || { echo "Error: Not a file." >&2; exit 1; }
TYPE=$(file -b --mime-type "$1")
xclip -selection clipboard -t "$TYPE" < "$1"
```

Action:

```
/home/user/path/to/script %F
```